# Animate and resize div dynamic height according to content size

Tags: jquery, dynamic, resize, jquery-animate, height

Does anyone know if it's possible to animate the resize of a div so that it's exactly the right size for the content? The height has to be dynamic, meaning if I resize the browser window then the div will increase/decrease in height. I already have a dynamic width of 80% of viewport.

This is what I use to animate the resize of a container currently, and the resizing part works, but the animation does not play for the resizing. When I had the height set to a fixed height, say:

```
$(".pagecontainer").animate({
    height: '700px'
}, 500);
```

It animated. But if I have height: 'auto', then it won't animate, simply just snaps to the new size.

JS:

```
<script>

    function setContainerHeight() {
        $(".pagecontainer").animate({
            height: 'auto'
        }, 500);
    }

    $('.link').on('click', function(e){
        $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut(0);
        setContainerHeight();
        $(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn();
    });

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.pagecontainer {
min-height:450px;
width:80%;
min-width:800px;
padding:50px 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.pagecontainer>div{
display: none; /*wait until page needs to be faded in*/
padding-left:50px;
padding-right:50px;
position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pagecontainer">

    <a href="#page1" class="link">page 1</a>
    <a href="#page2" class="link">page 2</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="link">page 3</a>

    <div id="page1">TONS OF TEXT HERE</div>

    <div id="page2">A BIT OF TEXT HERE</div>

    <div id="page3">BUNCH OF IMAGES</div>

</div>
```

Say for example page 1 has tons of text, I don't know what height it will take up as the height itself is dynamic, if I widen the browser window then obviously height needed will shrink. Page 2 might only have a bit of text, so the height needed will be much smaller. Page 3 has a bunch of images but I don't know the height required to fit them all (which is the point of my question, letting the script calculate how much height is needed).

How do I resize ".pagecontainer" so that its height **perfectly fits the content on each page even when I resize browser window**? For example if I click page1, then the container will enlarge (animated with jQuery's .animate() ), then if I click page2, then container will shrink.

Here is an image description: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bkAG.png

Thanks.

Comment: I have hard to understand your question. How could I both have a perfect fit of the content and at the same time resize with the browser window? The only way I can think is to resize the contents as well but that isn't your point is it?

Comment: Um the container will resize with the browser window. I have it set up at 80%. Means when I make the viewport smaller, the container get smaller, and more height will be required. Say for example a height of 400px is needed when viewport is full size, to fit a huge block of text, with width at 80% (make up a number, say at 80% width is 1000px). If I resize viewport to 50%, then let's say now height needs to be 700px to fit all the text, width is still 80% of current viewport (now it would be 500px). I don't get what's confusing about it?

Comment: Default setting for any div is `height: auto;` which normally gets "perfect fit" ? `$(".pagecontainer").animate({ height: 'auto'}, 500);` should work?

Comment: D'oh I forgot there was an auto option for height. Thanks that worked for the resizing part, but now it's not animating. Before when I had height: '700px' or any fixed height, it animated the resizing. Now I have it at auto it won't animate anymore. (I will edit the question now)

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason I can see to calculate the height - the height will automatically change for you.

**jQuery**

```
$('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut(0);

$('.link').on('click', function(e){
    $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut(0);
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn();
});
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<a href="#page1" class="link">page 1</a>
<a href="#page2" class="link">page 2</a>
<a href="#page3" class="link">page 3</a>

<div class="pagecontainer">

    <div id="page1">Block One</div>
    <div id="page2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></div>
    <div id="page3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" /></div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/tmuC2/

## **Edit**

Based on your comments, you need it to animate up and down instead of fading in and out. To do so, use `animate([height:"show",speed)` and `animate([height:"hide",speed)` as shown here:

```
    $('.pagecontainer>div').animate({height:"hide"},500);
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).animate({height:"show"},500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/tmuC2/1/

Comment: Thanks, but the fade in/out is for the page content itself. I want the content to fade out when I click link to another page.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it there is no need for the function `expandPageContainer()` - the animation takes place when no container is visible and you don't need to calculate any absolute value for height.

Just remove the function and function call for `expandPageContainer()` and set your container CSS to `height: auto` and the behaviour you expect will happen. Resizing containers to fit its content with regard to height is a default behaviour. (You might want to remove the `margin-bottom` rule)

Also calling `fadeOut(0)` is the same as `hide()`. The latter is a little more efficient.